# Disable check-boxes using a function with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have a question about how to uncheck check-boxes inside ng-repeat, when the ng-model is already in use?

This is the construction:

**The object:**

```
$scope.wines = [

    { "name": "Wine a", "type": "white", "country": "italie", "style": "medium" },
    { "name": "Wine a", "type": "white", "country": "france", "style": "light" },
    { "name": "Wine a", "type": "white", "country": "france", "style": "sweet" }
  ];
  $scope.winetypes = {white : true, red: true};
  $scope.whitetypes = {light : false,medium : false,sweet : false};

});
```

**HTML**

```
    <li ng-repeat="(type, value) in winetypes">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="winetypes[type]" /> {{type}}
    </li>


   <li ng-repeat="(style, value) in whitetypes">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="whitetypes[style]" /> {{style}}
    </li>

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="wine in wines | winetypefilter:winetypes |whitefilter:whitetypes">
        {{wine.name}} is a {{wine.type}} with {{wine.style}} style from {{wine.country}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

- **My wish:**  the  check-boxes linked to the **whitetypes** (light, medium, sweet) would be automatically unchecked, when the **white** check-box would be unchecked. I guess ng-model can't be used to achieve my wishes, because it's already in use.

I tried without success:

```
$scope.white= function() {
  if($scope.winetypes.white = false) {
    return $scope.whitetypes = {light: false, medium: false, sweet: false}
};

$scope.white;
```

The demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nIQ2lkiJJY9MwJKHrqOk?p=preview

Comment: do you also want that when you check white all white related attributes checked as well???

Comment: the idea was only uncheck the  related attributes, when the white checkbox is unchecked. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***first decide what action you want...***

- You want to change a checkbox model and it's value should effect
  other checkbox values...

***so first solutions that come to my minds are...***

- `ng-change` (because your wish is about changing a checkbox attribute)
- `ng-click` (for changing checkbox attribute you should click that input)
- `ng-checked` (set condition to be checked or unchecked)

ok let's move on our solution... After analysing these three (there can be more solutions) `ng-change` is best for this scenario because it guarantees that binded fucntion will be execute after user changed value of checkbox... for more details check [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

***first edit your html...***

```
<li ng-repeat="(type, value) in winetypes">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="winetypes[type]" ng-change="disableRelatedStyles(type, winetypes[type])"/> {{type}}
</li>
```

***and add our new function (disableRelatedStyles) to our controller...***

```
  $scope.disableRelatedStyles = function (type, value) {
    if (type == 'white' && !value) {
      for(var style in $scope.whitetypes) {
         $scope.whitetypes[style] = false;
      }
    }
  };
```

and finally a working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/YBTLqgO0rZitDTYeJodo?p=preview)...

Comment: Hi wickY26, thanks a lot for you help and explanation!! I understood very well how your function works! I didn't know the ng-change command, and how to use it. Really it's very powerful, it's nice the idea using !value to check if 'white' is false or not!! Thanks of your help, I understand better AngularJS! Regards, stéphane

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use `ng-click` and `$timeout` to handle every click to the white checkbox.

```
$scope.click_handler = function (type) {
    if (type == 'white') {
        $timeout(function () {
            if ($scope.winetypes[type] === false) {
                $scope.wines.forEach(function (e) {
                    if (e.type == 'white') {
                        $scope.whitetypes[e.style] = false;
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
};
```

The `$timeout` is necessary since we want to wait for ng-model to update first. Make sure you are injecting `$timeout` into the controller.

in markup

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="click_handler(type)" ng-model="winetypes[type]" /> {{type}}
```

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gErMmwzPhhiI2YIOXFGt?p=preview)

Comment: Hi XrXrXr, thanks a lot for your help!! $timeout was unknown for me, now I understood how it works!! Really, it help me too understand better AngularJS inside the context. Regards, Stéphane

Comment: btw $timeout is just Angular's wrapper of window.setTimeout, nothing special about it